# What was Starbuck’s role?

Tags: tv, battlestar-galactica

I’m confused about Starbuck’s role towards the end of the Battlestar Galactica remake.

> She disappeared into a wormhole and returned, having found “earth”. Later, she finds her own body on “earth”, suggesting she "died" then came back, only to vanish when talking to Lee in the final episode.

Was she an angel?

Comment: should probably have a spoiler alert (although it's been over for a year or more)

Comment: If this was english.stackexchange, I'd answer: The first mate of Ahab on the Pequod in Moby Dick. ;-)

Comment: This spoiler box does not work at all. Because when you see this in Questions page, the spoiler text is in the summary for this question. You are spoiled even if you don't come to this page :(

Comment: That was added in there by another user, but I'm open to suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: she was one of the white mice ;)

Comment: i believe that she was a cylon from earth and left after the destruction to the colonies whos to say she wasnt adopted haha

Comment: Not even Ronald D. Moore knows.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I had assumed she was an angel, or maybe something like a [Seraph](https://galactica.fandom.com/wiki/Seraph). The latter would make a nice tie-in to the original series.

Of course, it could easily be she was a loose plot thread. We certainly have no shortage of those in modern TV serials.

Comment: I too, assumed this. That she was homage to the ... what were they called ... Beings of Light or something like that, in the original series.

Comment: But what was the body of Starbucks they found on hearth in the destroyed ship then?

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark, That was the loose plot thread.

Answer (score 83):

I believe that Starbuck was a loose plot thread that the writers had a difficult time tying up in a meaningful way.

The problem probably all started when the staff killed Starbuck off, which worked great dramatically until they realized they lost one of the show's most popular characters.  Then the writers brought Starbuck back with a great mysterious resurrection, making viewers believe she might be a Cylon.  So I'm sure the writers sat around and tried to think up what would top being a Cylon.  And unfortunately they couldn't think of anything so they just BSed their way through the last episode.

**Update October 2013** - [Ronald Moore talks about Starbuck's fate](http://sciencefiction.com/2013/10/21/ron-moore-finally-opens-end-battlestar-galactica/):

> I liked the idea, conceptually, that her fate was ambiguous because,
>   conceptually, we were tying her to whatever the power was that didn’t
>   like to be called God and was involved from the inception. From the
>   miniseries on, there’s definitely something else going on in this
>   story, and it’s unknowable. I kind of felt like it should be
>   unknowable. It felt wrong to give it a neat answer on something that
>   was so profound and existential about these people and this situation.
>   They were dealing with something that they had trouble defining,
>   whether it was gods plural, or God singular, or something else out
>   there. Starbuck was in some way representational of that power, or had
>   some connection to it, having been brought back from the dead —
>   literally. I just didn’t feel like I wanted to give it a “Oh, that’s
>   what this means.” It just felt right that that, too, should be
>   mysterious and unknowable. That’s the way I wanted to go. If I called
>   her an angel, does that make everybody happy? That just seemed really
>   unsatisfying. I don’t know what that means. That’s just putting a
>   label on who she is and it doesn’t tell me anything more, really.

Comment: Almost certainly. Having been in a few writer's rooms, this is exactly how it goes. If they had some awesome solution, they would have made DAMN sure we all knew what the deal was.

Comment: That unexplained downvote was "cold as iicccceeeeee!"

Comment: Nonsense. She had "a destiny" all the way through, and when she died the angel Leoben was trying to get her over her fear of death so that she could be reborn and become an angel/guide/whatever. She was to meet the other angels ("they're waiting for me") in order to get on with her destiny. At no stage in Maelstrom did this seem ambiguous, so it's odd that you think the writers just "made it up" an entire two calendar years later.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: My impression was that other than the rockin' final battle, I felt the explanation was anti-climatic and mostly unsatisfying.

Comment: @Mark: That is not at all the same as "the writers had a difficult time tying [it] up in a meaningful way" and/or all the rest of the inflammatory nonsense that you spewed in your answer.

Comment: @Tomalak - I'm not trying to make you angry, but the top voted answer with +33 upvotes is rarely inflammatory nonsense.

Comment: @Mark: Regardless, that's what this is. I'm taking the words for what they are, not relying on the assessment of a handful of other people on the internet. I pointed out the blatant discrepancy in my original comment, but this hasn't been referred to in your follow-ups.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - Well thanks for your opinion, I'm sorry we couldn't see eye-to-eye.  I encourage you to participate and vote on the site, have a good day.

Comment: Considering that they had planned out the last season in a major arc that could be divided into two parts, in case the last half never was able to complete production and air, then I don't think you can say they wrote themselves into a corner.  If you read Ron Moore's comments on blogs and elsewhere, it's pretty clear that whole season was planned out in advance, so they could have killed her or not, whichever they wanted, before her death was even filmed.

Comment: Roger Moore explicitly says in the podcast of director's comments that accompanies the episode when Starbuck returns that he had known all along she would return. He even explains how he kept it a secret from other cast members, and how he had lied in an earlier podcast about all the decisions leading to removing her from the show. However, he never (so far as I remember from all his podcasts) explains how and why she returns. I believe he decided to leave it unexplained, preferring to leave it to audience interpretation.

Comment: Sounds like he probably shouldn't have kept it a secret since it was such a bad idea from a writing perspective in my opinion.

Comment: She's a Seraph, along with Leobin, who was pretty confused from her amnesia towards her True Purpose. Much like a lot of us light workers who are just now activing in the Real World.

Comment: haha true true . . . . .

Comment: The amount of meandering in his update makes me think he was just BSing his way through the explanation...

Answer (score 40):

I've always figured she was the same thing that Head Six and Head Baltar were.  Only visible to everyone and unaware of her own status.  And Baltar's line at the end when Six calls their boss "god" seemed to suggest that whatever it was, it wasn't god.

> You know it doesn't like to be called
>   that.

So it seems she was the creation of some sort of very powerful godlike entity.  I imagined it as something like the ascended from Stargate.  Energy being perhaps.  And Head Six, Head Baltar, and Starbuck were all probably also similar beings -- only with out awareness of their abilities.

This is of course, total speculation.  Which is about all any of us can provide in answer unless some book or interview has provided a solid answer.

Comment: While I think Mark Rogers explanation is closer to the truth in reality (what others sometimes call 'Our reality'). Your answer is what I figured for the BSG *reality*.

Comment: Oh, Mark Roger's answer is absolutely the answer for *our* reality.  But I figured the question was about BSG reality. ;)

Comment: i like your answer, however in an VH1 interview Ronald D. Moore said she isn't a common hallucination, so it won't be the ultimate answer although it would explain her role. I guess shes more of an jesus-like prophet - jesus was a prophet too and revived from the dead, making him the salvator.

Comment: @Samuel Yes, but you could be misinterpreting RDM: I always assumed that Head Baltar and Head Six were more than just hallucinations.

Comment: Yes! They're called Seraphs in the original BSG and played a much larger role there. Their functional equivalent would be descended Ancients with temporary amnesia in the SG-1 universe.

Comment: +1 because you at least tried to give an in-universe answer as opposed to the most-upvoted answer.

Answer (score 10):

Starbuck was originally a human soldier who died in a crash landing of her viper on Earth, after flying there through the eye of the storm. The Starbuck that returns after her disappearance is not Starbuck at all, but an angel of death in Starbuck's form, sent by God to lead the colonists to Earth and ultimately to help bring about the destruction of cylons and humans alike, save for the few settlers of New Earth.

A.K.A. Deus ex machina

Comment: This has many loose ends, like her connection with Leobin, the drawing of the Vortex, especially as a child, etc. I think she just had far less amnesia as to her true purpose after she was reinserted into their space/time dimension.

Answer (score 6):

I somehow had a theory that she was the child of the lost Cylon, who somehow mysteriously re-appeared. Again, this is just speculation, but that was always my thought.

Comment: The episode where she has a vision of her dad playing the piano led me to the same idea.  But RDM denied that her dad was the lost Cylon skinjob Daniel.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  Not only would it tie up nearly everything from before the Writer's Strike very neatly, it would've given them an amazing chance to show history repeating itself by placing the remake into the same continuity as the original...

Comment: This... I still think she's the real first human-cylon cross bred by poor Daniel... RDM is just trying to fool us by denying it! :)

Answer (score 5):

I had always thought she was the daughter of a Daniel the 7th cylon.  So she might have been the first cylon human hybrid.  Explaining her resurection / dead body on the cylon homeworld requires about as many blue berry muffins as the Angel theory.

Comment: The episode where she has a vision of her dad playing the piano led me to the same idea. But RDM denied that her dad was the lost Cylon skinjob Daniel. (yes, I posted this to two answers.)

Comment: This would have been a great way to resolve the plot thread!

Comment: Same as above comment... I still think it this way, whatever RDM says... :P

Answer (score 3):

In the BSG universe

- "angels" like Head(s) Six and Balthar are possible, though invisible and perhaps immaterial, yet
- humans can "walk with the gods" on Kobol, and the gods can subsequently escort the survivors of said humans to new solar systems (presumably being material in the process, and perhaps visible)

If those two sorts of beings are both possible, then why presume that Starbuck was an angel. Why couldn't her nature be the same as the nature of the Lords of Kobol (though no doubt of lesser degree)?

Comment: They called them Seraphs, and, yes, the Heads, Lords, and Starbuck are probably the same class of entities.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I see two possibilities:

- She's a Seraph/Being of Light like in the original series, and that's that
- She's an avatar of some kind, and the BSG universe is actually a simulation like Caprica's V-world

These two options aren't necessarily mutually exclusive. After watching Caprica, it would not be a huge stretch to take what is learned through V-world and how the Cylons came to be, then extrapolate that the universe that is presented in BSG is just another abstraction layer above V-world.

This would explain the hybrids and their prophecies (perhaps they are hooked into the source code of the universe), and would explain the angels and godlike individuals both in the series and in the backstory.

The key difference between the V-world and the BSG universe would be conscious awareness -- V-world participants have consciousness about their external lives, most of the characters presented in BSG do not, and likely do not have lives outside of the simulation. I would posit that Head Six and Head Baltar have awareness and have existences outside of the simulation, and the being that shall not be named "God" is perhaps the architect of the simulation. Starbuck is something of a glitch, or perhaps had been "installed" by "God", and was sent back after exercising her free will to commit suicide because her role was too important.

This does mean she is literally a Deus Ex Machina entity -- which isn't necessarily a bad thing. I'd hesitate to label anything that can't be understood at face value as "bad writing", not everything can or should be told in a story without abstraction. TV used to be without abstract concepts -- everything was as it was told, and as it has improved as a storytelling media that has begun to melt away and if often incorrectly assumed to be just a result of bad storytelling. I would suggest that her reappearance in season 4 and disappearance at the end of the series is too blatant to be a mistake -- remember, she returned within a few episodes, too few to be a result of fan reaction (plus they filmed her return scene around the same time they filmed her death).

So, take the obvious anomaly that she is to infer something about the universe the story inhabits.

Answer (score -3):

a script is like a movie set. it appears complete and real but its really lots of patchwork to make it appear that way (especially over multiple seasons) and if you would move the camera a bit to the right, you would immediately notice that its pretty much just covering the scenes and otherwise ends apruptly. its no encyclopedia which covers every detail.

this smells like a simple hole in the plot and it makes about as much sense as j.d. from scrubs getting run over by a steamroller and suddenly reappearing next week after his funeral, with some vague references to angels by the janitor.

in the ep where starbuck "died" we saw her ship exploding. no uncertanity, no guessing, just bang, which indicates that they really intended her to die at this point. then there was her magical reappearence and this absolutely unlogical wreck on earth with her body in it, which somehow survived the explosion and got teleported there it seems.

either they became desperate because their ratings were dropping or it was a blatant cliffhanger without any kind of logic, "lost" style, which would even more suck. its also no surprice that the producer claims it was always meant that way. sounds a hell of a lot better than admitting that they made mistakes. george lucas did this all the time when he talked about the starwars movies while there were drastical plot changes all the time during shooting them.

Answer (score -4):

What if Starbuck simply *became* a Cylon (with the same lack of self-awareness as the sleepers)? The show's tech existed for genetic cloning, so it would be fairly simple for the Cylons to get a DNA sample & make another model...